# What's the simplest way of defining lexicographic comparison for elements of a class?

Tags: c++, lexicographic

If I have a class that I want to be able to sort (ie support a less-than concept), and it has several data items such that I need to do lexicographic ordering then I need something like this:

```
struct MyData {
  string surname;
  string forename;

  bool operator<(const MyData& other) const {
    return surname < other.surname || (surname==other.surname && forename < other.forename); }
};
```

This becomes pretty unmanageable for anything with more than 2 data members.  Are there any simpler ways of achieving it? The data members may be any Comparable class.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With the advent of C++11 there's a new and concise way to achieve this using [std::tie](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie):

```
bool operator<(const MyData& other) const {
  return std::tie(surname, forename) < std::tie(other.surname, other.forename);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

`tuple` is a good idea, but if you want to keep having names for your member variables, it might be good enough to restructure your comparison function like this:

```
struct MyData {
    string surname;
    string forename;
    string var;
    // ...

    bool operator<(const MyData& other) const {
        if (surname != other.surname) return surname < other.surname;
        if (forename != other.forename) return forename < other.forename;
        if (var != other.var) return var < other.var;

        // ...

        return false; //< They are equal
    }
};
```

Depending on your taste, you might even want a macro like `#define COMPARE(field) if (field != other.field) return field < other.field;` to reduce duplication. Then the function would just become a list of `COMPARE`-invocations.

Comment: Maybe `#define LEX_LT(mem) if(mem != other.mem) return mem < other.mem` and then chain them as `LEX_LT(surname); LEX_LT(forename); LEX_LT(var); ...; return false;`

Comment: I like the layout of that, it's much more manageable and less error-prone than the nested-if.  I'm not averse to occasional macro use, and that could be handy for larger structures, but I think the basic form is clear enough.

Answer (score 7):

You could store the data in a `boost::tuple`, which provides lexicographic comparison, and provide named accessor functions, along the lines of:

```
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple_comparison.hpp>

struct Data {
    string &surname()  {return stuff.get<0>();}
    string &forename() {return stuff.get<1>();}

    // it would be polite to add const overloads too.

    bool operator<(const Data &other) const {return stuff < other.stuff;}

private:
    boost::tuple<string, string> stuff;
};
```

I believe this is also available as `std::tr1::tuple`, and will be `std::tuple` in the forthcoming standard.

Maintaining the list of accessors is probably more manageable than maintaining the comparison code.

Comment: Interesting solution.  It seems a shame to lose the named fields though as seeing the class's contents in the debugger becomes more difficult.

Comment: You can keep the named fields and use the tuple only for comparison purposes, e.g `return boost::tie(surname, forename) < boost::tie(other.surname, other.forename);`

Comment: Even better, wrap `tie` in a member function. Then you only have to maintain a single list of the lexicographical order.

Comment: Neat - I hadn't come across boost::tie() before

Answer (score 3):

If all members have the same type you could put them in `std::vector`. By default `std::lexicographical_compare` will be used to compare vectors.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`boost::tuple`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html#relational_operators) or `std::pair` which has built-in lexigraphical comparison. Of course the disadvantage is you can't associate a method to the tuples.