# How to map a bool to a 3d point struct with std::map?

Tags: c++, dictionary

How do I use the following struct:

```
struct point 
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};
```

as a key for `std::map<point, bool>`? How should I define `operator<` for two points?

Comment: How do you want the points to be ordered? Or is the order not important?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: It must, at least, be a strict weak ordering.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator< and strict weak ordering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979759/operator-and-strict-weak-ordering)

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: The order doesn't matter

Comment: And you're sure you wouldn't like points adjacent in your map to be close to each other in this 3D space? Because then you'd need a fractal mapping, which is much more complicated to implement.

Comment: Not a duplicate.  The asker of the linked question was unable to use `::boost::make_tuple`, but this OP might be able to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way of defining lexicographic comparison for elements of a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500664/whats-the-simplest-way-of-defining-lexicographic-comparison-for-elements-of-a-cl)

Comment: @finnw: IMO the question "how should I define operator<" isn't "how can I make a pointless wrapper around an object that, for whatever reason, I'm not using in the first place". In fairness this may be more of a related question than a duplicate.

Comment: +1 this question anyway for (a) apparently coders with high reputation will routinely implement this wrong, even failing to understand _weak strict ordering_ (b) even I learned a valuable trick in the process \

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Standard library containers like `std::map` require that your ordering is a "Strict Weak Ordering", so you have to be very careful when designing one.

The typical approach for a 3-ary tuple looks like this:

```
bool operator<(const point& other) const
{
   if (x != other.x)
       return (x < other.x);

   if (y != other.y)
       return (y < other.y);

   return (z < other.z);
}
```

It's like a comparator for just `x`, but with the difference that if the two `x`s are the same, you fall through to compare `y`s. If they are the same, then similarly you fall through to the `z` comparison.

Comment: `Strict Weak Ordering` is an oxymoron? :P

Comment: @Nawaz: No; "strict" and "weak" are orthogonal (I think you're confusing "strict" for "strong", or confusing "weak" for "relaxed"). [Have a read of this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the link. (BTW, my comment was meant to be taken in amusement. Sad :()

Comment: @Nawaz: Oh, oops. I do struggle with your sarcasm sometimes ;)

Answer (score 6):

Of course, `boost::tuple<int,int,int>` would make this utterly unnecessary.

**Update** Adding the all-inclusive have-your-cake-and-eat-it-too no-drawback solution here. IMHO it rocks!

```
#include <boost/tuple/tuple_comparison.hpp>

struct point 
{
    int x, y, z;
    point(int x, int y, int z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
    bool operator<(const point& rhs) const 
    {
        return boost::tie(x, y, z) < boost::tie(rhs.x, rhs.y, rhs.z);
    }
};
```

Here is the kicker: it all optimizes away. Compile:

```
int main()
{
    point a(1,2,3), b(3,2,1);
    bool lt = a<b;
    return lt?0:255;
}
```

With g++ -O2 yields the following in assembly.

```
main:
.LFB1132:
        pushl   %ebp
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        popl    %ebp
        ret
.LFE1132:
```

The compiler was able to optimize the whole of this program to ... `return 0` effectively. That is pretty neat.

---

Here goes the simple answer:

```
struct point 
{
    point(int x, int y, int z) 
        : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    bool operator<(const point& rhs) const 
    {
        if (x<rhs.x) return true;
        if (x==rhs.x) 
        { 
            if (y<rhs.y) return true;
            if (y==rhs.y) return z<rhs.z;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Also, I would consider looking for a redefinition of my struct that will allow using std::lexicographical_compare

```
#include <algorithm>

// ...
bool operator<(const point& rhs) const 
{
    return std::lexicographical_compare(&xyz, &xyz+3, &rhs.xyz, &rhs.xyz+3);
}
```

Comment: By adding a constructor to the struct `point`, you made it non-POD. It was previously POD.

Comment: @finnw: POD cannot have *user-defined* constructor. See [Can't C++ POD type have any constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442717/cant-c-pod-type-have-any-constructor)

Comment: @finnw, @Nawaz: Good points about POD struct (removing 'recommendation'). However, I have added a brainwave based on boost::tie() from Boost Tuple. It totally eradicates the competition :)

Comment: @finnw: You shouldn't have deleted the comment. It's helpful for others. Deletion makes the discussion look weird. :P

Answer (score 1):

One lazy way to do it:

```
bool operator<( point const &pt ) const
{
    return ::boost::make_tuple(x,y,z) <
           ::boost::make_tuple(pt.x,pt.y,pt.z);
}
```

Comment: That gave me a terrific idea, will update my answer in 5 minutes after I test that!

Comment: Wouldn't `tie` be better and faster?

Comment: @Xeo, I don't know about that.  It creates a temporary struct of references instead of a temporary struct of values.  Both could be optimized away by the compiler.  But if they are not, then you have introduced an extra layer of indirection.

Comment: @Xeo: we think alike once again, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109445/how-to-map-a-bool-to-a-3d-point-struct-with-stdmap/6109591#6109591; That is some feat of optimization there! (_Of course I needed to see the disassembly before posting a solution based on `tie()`_!)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to write this is like this:

```
bool operator<(const point& p) const
{
    if(x < p.x)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(p.x < x)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if( y < p.y)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if( p.y < y)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if( z < p.z)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(p.z < z)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: No. This does not satisfy strict weak ordering.

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Rather verbose!

Comment: My versions (both of them) are both shorter and simpler, so I can't really agree

Answer (score 0):

if they're supposed to be ordered in a certain way, you'll want to specify that exact way (for example by euclidean distance from 0/0/0). If all you want is to distinguish different points, you could do something like

```
x == x2 ? (y == y2 ?  (z < z2) : y < y2) : x < x2
```

Comment: No. You should only fall through to the `y` case if the `x`s are _not equal_. If `x > x2`, the answer is immediately `false`.

Answer (score -1):

Just a guess guys,

```
bool operator<(const point& other) const
{
  return( memcmp( (void*) this, (void*) &other, sizeof(point)) < 0);
}
```

Of course, the order is kind of weird since x,y and z are signed values, but this should be suitable to order into a std::map, isn't it ?

Comment: What on earth are you doing? >.<

Comment: I think your should consider this solution.

Comment: I can provide more code is your are still skeptical about it. But since the `point` struct contain only 3 int and is **not virtual**, the size of the struct is 3 int long and the `(void*)` casting place the compare method on the first int ! Comparing the memory print of 3 **aligned** `int` is a way to compare them with uniqueness guarantee.