# Passing std::set to method in C++

Tags: c++, set, pass-by-reference, std

Given the following prerequisits:

**shared.h**

```
struct A {
    int x;
    int y;
}

typedef set<A> setOfA;
```

**implementation1.cpp**

```
#include "shared.h"
void Implementation1::someFunction()
{
    //...
    setOfA setinstance;
    //...
    Implementation2* i = new Implementation2();
    i->functionF(setinstance);
}
```

**implementation2.h**

```
#include "shared.h"
void Implementation2::functionF(setOfA&);
```

*EDIT: now this should be clearer...*

I want to pass a `setOfA` to another function of a different class - everything is compiling just fine. I get the following linker problem:

> undefined reference to `'implementation::functionF(std::set<A, std::less<A>, std::allocator<A> >&)'`

Just to get it right - the implementation could not be found, right? This cannot be a typedef problem, because everything compiles just fine... What am I missing here?

Comment: Your type `A` has an `operator<` that you omitted, right?

Comment: Have you implemented `functionF`? Are you including the source file that contains it when you build the program?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes yes, aswell as an `operator==`

Comment: @MikeSeymour I edit my post to get a MWE, just a second...

Answer (score 5):

The linker is unable to find the **definition** of `void functionF(setOfA&);`

Somewhere, you need:

```
void Implementation2::functionF(setOfA&) {
    ...
}
```

*Just to elaborate on this slightly, shouldn't you have an implementation2.cpp file that implements the above code?*

Answer (score 2):

You didn't define a comparator for `A`, so a set of them can't exist.

Define a function:

```
bool operator<(A& const lhs, A& const rhs)
```

and ensure that it implements a *[strict weak ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6109518/560648)*; in this case, probably:

```
bool operator<(A& const lhs, A& const rhs) {
    if (lhs.x != rhs.x)
       return (lhs.x < rhs.x);

    return (lhs.y < rhs.y);
}
```

Comment: You're right, but shouldn't this cause a compiler error instead of a linker error?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Um, maybe. Hmm.

Answer (score 1):

My major problem was that I was working in the wrong namespace. I agree to close this thread, because it's probably just helping me with my specific problem - on the other hand the hint to implement the `operator<` gave me the clue. For the sake of completeness, here's my `operator<` implementation.

```
bool operator<(const A& e) const {
if (x != e.x)
  return x < e.x;
else
  return y < e.y;
}
```

Comment: Good, but prefer a non-member function.