# c++ class double sorting(?)

Tags: c++, class, sorting

I'd like to write code using class double sorting(?).

For example, class has three data member i.e. `num`, `error`, and `data`.

```
class Test
{
public:
    int num;
    float error;
    vector<float> data;
};
```

Now, I make:

```
vector<Test> TestList;
```

and, those have:

> TestList[0] : num = 1, error = 0.001, data0
>
> TestList[1] : num = 1, error = 0.01, data1
>
> TestList[2] : num = 2, error = 0.01, data2
>
> TestList[3] : num = 3, error = 0.001, data3
>
> TestList[4] : num = 3, error = 0.01, data4

Then, I want to sort them with `num` (higher priority) and `error`.
The expected result is the `TestList` is arranged as following order:

> Test[4] : num = 3, error = 0.001, data4
>
> Test[3] : num = 3, error = 0.01, data3
>
> Test[2] : num = 2, error = 0.01, data2
>
> Test[0] : num = 1, error = 0.001, data0
>
> Test[1] : num = 1, error = 0.01, data1

How can I do this? In addition, how can I call this algorithm?

Comment: Look for a sort that is documented as a "stable" sort, then sort first by `error`, then `num`. e.g. mergesort is a stable sort algorithm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way of defining lexicographic comparison for elements of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500664/whats-the-simplest-way-of-defining-lexicographic-comparison-for-elements-of-a-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order you're referring to is called 
[Lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)

You could simply sort your `vector<Test>` with [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) by providing either a suitable comparator, or by implementing `operator<`, as explained in [Sorting a vector of custom objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects)

The last implementation could be something like:

```
class Test
{
public:
    int num;
    float error;
    vector<float> data;
    bool operator<( const X& val ) const
    { 
      if (num > val.num)
      {
        return true;
      }
      else if (num == val.num && error < val.error)
      {
        return true;
      }
      else
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement operator `<` in Test

   ```
   class Test {
   public:
       int num;
       float error;
       vector<float> data;

       bool operator < (const Test & val)const
       { 
         return num > val.num || num == val.num && error < val.error; 
       }
   };
   ```
2. use `std::sort` to sort

   ```
   sort(TestList.begin(), TestList.end());
   ```

Comment: I guess is a tipo: should be `num < val.num` with smaller not greater.

Comment: @AdrianMaire OP wants num sorted descending

Comment: You cannot make a comparison operator to behave wrong/non-intuitive just for a single case of vector sorting: why if 20 line further you need another sorting but ascending? Use reverse iteration.

Comment: If you need to sort in another way, you can provide another comparison function to std::sort. Operator < is the default way. In this case, both are acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

`std::sort` takes a comparer, so you can use:

```
std::vector<Test> tests /* = ...*/;

std::sort(tests.begin(), test.end(), [](const Test& lhs, const Test& rhs)
    {
        return std::tie(rhs.num, rhs.error) < std::tie(lhs.num, lhs.error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), and provide a comparison function object.

```
auto NumDescErrorAsc = [](const Test & lhs, const Test & rhs)
{ return std::tie(rhs.num, lhs.error) < std::tie(lhs.num, rhs.error); };
auto NumAscErrorAsc = [](const Test & lhs, const Test & rhs)
{ return std::tie(lhs.num, lhs.error) < std::tie(rhs.num, rhs.error); };

sort(TestList.begin(), TestList.end(), NumDescErrorAsc); // Required order

sort(TestList.begin(), TestList.end(), NumAscErrorAsc); // Original order
```

This works because `std::tuple::operator<` provides an ordering based on the first value, with later values breaking ties. Note how we use the right hand side num on the left in `NumDescErrorAsc`. That's equivalent to using > for num.